# Why does my Graphic Card shows 4GB RAM in Intel software whereas CPU-Z shows 11GB

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

As you can see that Intel scanned my hardware and found that my Graphic Card: Gigabyte Windforce OC 11GB RTX 2080Ti 4GB, whereas CPU-Z shows 11GB.

Could someone explain this please?

[image]

Comment: Why are you looking at an Intel website for the specifications of a Nvidia product?    What Intel tool to you use to scan your system?  How much memory are you sharing with the Intel iGPU?  Please edit your question so I can improve my answer.

Comment: @Ramhound sure, will do it once I'm back to home. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see that Intel scanned my hardware and found that my Graphic Card: Gigabyte Windforce OC 11GB RTX 2080Ti 4GB

The information on the Intel page is incorrect, there is no version of the RTX 2080 Ti, that comes with only 4 GB of VRAM.  Whatever, Intel is using to detect the VRAM of your GPU, is likely being confused by the existance of the Nvidia GPU in your system.  **The information in the screenshot, on the Intel website is incorrect, and the data contained in the page cannot be trusted.**  The screenshot also clearly indicates the GPU is sharing 4 GB worth of your physical system memory.

**Based on the screenshot I suspect, whatever generated the information, is deeply flawed.**